# Custom Identity Verification (Verify) Page

Tags: apex, lightning-community

I would like to verify community user using email address to confirm their identity using initRegisterVerificationMethod / verifyRegisterVerificationMethod in custom VFP. Below apex code when executed from Developer Console gives "Failed to get network info." error:

```
String userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
User u = [Select email, MobilePhone, Id from User Where Id=:userId];
//String mPh = getFormattedSms(u.MobilePhone); //Not sure why type cast issue (String) from the type anon is generated.
String exceptionText = System.UserManagement.initRegisterVerificationMethod(Auth.VerificationMethod.SMS);
System.Debug(exceptionText); //Same network error
exceptionText = System.UserManagement.initRegisterVerificationMethod(Auth.VerificationMethod.EMAIL);
System.Debug(exceptionText); //Same network error
```

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it? Also how does above iniRVM method knows which mobile/email id to consider?

I do not find the below links to be clear.
Reference 1: [Create Your Own Verify Page for Community Sign-Ups](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_identity_login_custom_verify_pages.htm)
Reference 2: [Create a Custom Identity Verification (Verify) Page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/external_identity_passwordless_custom_verification.htm)